# Most efficient way to insert test records for every Opportunity stage

Tags: apex, unit-test

For a test class I need to insert 7 Opportunities with different StageName values as I reference them in my class. I figure I can add them one at a time to a list and then insert the list. Thus, it would like like this:

```
List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();

// Create Opportunities
    Opportunity oppy1 = new Opportunity();
        oppy.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
        oppy.RecordTypeId = recordTypeOpp[0].Id;
        oppy.CloseDate = System.today();
        oppy.StageName = 'Prospecting/Business Issue Identified';
        oppy.Type = 'New Customer';
        oppy.ContractTerm__c = 12;
        oppy.CurrencyISOCode = 'USD';
        oppy.AccountId = acc.Id;
        oppy.Practice__c = prac.Id;
        oppy.Probability = 100;
        oppy.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c = System.today();
    opps.add(oppy1);

    Opportunity oppy2 = new Opportunity();
        oppy.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
        oppy.RecordTypeId = recordTypeOpp[0].Id;
        oppy.CloseDate = System.today();
        oppy.StageName = 'Scoping/Building Business Case';
        oppy.Type = 'New Customer';
        oppy.ContractTerm__c = 12;
        oppy.CurrencyISOCode = 'USD';
        oppy.AccountId = acc.Id;
        oppy.Practice__c = prac.Id;
        oppy.Probability = 100;
        oppy.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c = System.today();
    opps.add(oppy2);

    Opportunity oppy3 = new Opportunity();
        oppy.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
        oppy.RecordTypeId = recordTypeOpp[0].Id;
        oppy.CloseDate = System.today();
        oppy.StageName = 'Proposal Development';
        oppy.Type = 'New Customer';
        oppy.ContractTerm__c = 12;
        oppy.CurrencyISOCode = 'USD';
        oppy.AccountId = acc.Id;
        oppy.Practice__c = prac.Id;
        oppy.Probability = 100;
        oppy.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c = System.today();
    opps.add(oppy3);
    ....
    insert opps;
```

is this the right approach? It seems inefficient and long if I have to repeat everything for one field change. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a matter of efficiency, you could write a "template" and then clone it:

```
Opportunity[] oppList = new Opportunity[0];
Opportunity template = 
    new Opportunity(
        Name='Test Opportunity',
        RecordTypeId=recordTypeOpp[0].Id,
        CloseDate=Date.Today(),
        Type='New Customer',
        ContractTerm__c=12,
        CurrencyISOCode='USD',
        AccountId=acc.Id,
        Practice__c=prac.Id,
        Probability=100,
        Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c=Date.today());
for(OpportunityStage stage: [SELECT MasterLabel FROM OpportunityStage WHERE IsActive = TRUE]) {
    Opportunity tempOpp = template.clone();
    oppList.add(tempOpp);
    tempOpp.StageName = stage.MasterLabel;
}
insert oppList;
```

Comment: I like that because it uses a List, and it data-drives the OpportunityStage values.  With different data constraints, the values that make each Opportunity would need to be hard-coded, but the SELECT here is nice.

Comment: I like this as it's dynamic for the possible stage values. I could see in the future  where changing the stagename would break the test, although I did hardcode the values in my class... Would this be better to use than the select?  Schema.DescribeFieldResult stages = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe();
  List<Schema.PicklistEntry> stageValues = stages.getPicklistValues();

Comment: @DanWooding I prefer the query because if you make changes, it can break your test. In other words, you *want* your test to break if you make a breaking configuration change (e.g. you remove/change/add a value), because it calls the break to your attention. This is generally good. Hard-coding is acceptable for that purpose, as is a query, as is a describe call. Whichever you want to do is okay, because any of the three could cause a break when a change is made.

Answer (score 1):

You can take this approach:

```
//prepare a list of stage names
List<String> lstStageNames = new List<String>{
                                'Prospecting/Business Issue Identified',
                                'Scoping/Building Business Case',
                                'Proposal Development',..};

Integer i =0;
List<Opportunity> lstOppty = new List<Opportunity>();

//iterate through the stages and create Opportunity record and add them to the list of Opportunity

for(String strStageName:lstStageNames)
{
    Opportunity oppy = new Opportunity();
    oppy.Name = 'Test Opportunity ' + i;
    oppy.RecordTypeId = getRecordTypeIdbyName('Opportunity', 'recordTypeName');
    oppy.CloseDate = System.today();
    oppy.StageName = strStageName;
    oppy.Type = 'New Customer';
    oppy.ContractTerm__c = 12;
    oppy.CurrencyISOCode = 'USD';
    oppy.AccountId = acc.Id;
    oppy.Practice__c = prac.Id;
    oppy.Probability = 100;
    oppy.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c = System.today(); 
    lstOppty.add(oppy);
    i++;
}
    insert lstOppty;


    public static Id getRecordTypeIdbyName(String objectName, String strRecordTypeName)
    {
        return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(strRecordTypeName).getRecordTypeId();
    }
```

Comment: It's certainly shorter, but doesn't offer any particular enhancement to speed (CPU time) than the original version.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have a single field that differs between each record, you can use `sObject.clone()` to make that setup more DRY.

```
    Opportunity oppy1 = new Opportunity();
    oppy1.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
    oppy1.RecordTypeId = recordTypeOpp[0].Id;
    oppy1.CloseDate = System.today();
    oppy1.StageName = 'Scoping/Building Business Case';
    oppy1.Type = 'New Customer';
    oppy1.ContractTerm__c = 12;
    oppy1.CurrencyISOCode = 'USD';
    oppy1.AccountId = acc.Id;
    oppy1.Practice__c = prac.Id;
    oppy1.Probability = 100;
    oppy1.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c = System.today();
    opps.add(oppy1);

    Opportunity oppy2, oppy3, oppy4, oppy5, oppy6, oppy7;
    oppy2 = oppy1.clone(false, true, false, false);
    oppy3 = oppy1.clone(false, true, false, false);
    oppy4 = oppy1.clone(false, true, false, false);
    oppy5 = oppy1.clone(false, true, false, false);
    oppy6 = oppy1.clone(false, true, false, false);
    oppy7 = oppy1.clone(false, true, false, false);

    oppy2.StageName = 'stage 2';
    oppy3.StageName = 'stage 3';
    oppy4.StageName = 'stage 4';
    oppy5.StageName = 'stage 5';
    oppy6.StageName = 'stage 6';
    oppy7.StageName = 'stage 7';

    opps.addAll(new List<Opportunity>{oppy2, oppy3, oppy4, oppy5, oppy6, oppy7});
```

<strike>Passing `TRUE` as the second argument to `clone()` makes it a 'deep' clone, meaning that when you change a field on the clone, it only changes the field on the clone.</strike>

The default behavior is to make a 'shallow' clone, where if you'd change a field on the clone, it'd also change the field on the original as well.

+edit: striking out incorrect information

Comment: Deep clone refers to cloning related (parent/child) references, not the actual field values. You can prove this to yourself with this [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/c743f212245d6dfe5fed16b494135028) I wrote for you. In short, your answer is definitely more efficient than the OP's code, but has some fallacies.

Comment: emphasizing DRY is really good, but the independent oppyX variables should be made into LIST elements.

Comment: @sfdcfox Skimming the documentation, and seeing the words 'full copy' and 'reference' as the main distinction between deep and shallow clones threw me off. Edited my answer.

Comment: @DerekF The documentation is lacking, I just wanted to make sure the right information got out there.

Comment: Can one of you link me to what DRY means? Google's not finding it for me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself